# improve nested ifelse statement in r

Tags: r

I have more than 10k address info, looks like "XXX street, city, state, US", in a character vector. 
I want to group them by states, so I use nested ifelse to get the address date.frame with two variable, add_info and state.

```
library(stringr)
for (i in nrow(address){
    ifelse(str_detect(address, 'Alabama'), address[i,state]='Alabama',
    ifelse(str_detect(address, 'Alaska'), address[i,state]='Alaska',
    ifelse(str_detect(address, 'Arizona'), address[i,state]='Arizona',
    ...
    ifelse(str_detect(address, 'Wyoming'), address[i,state]='Wyoming', address[i,state]=NA)...)
}
```

Of course, this is extremely inefficient, but I don't know how to rewrite this nested ifelse. Any idea?

Comment: Is the format always the same? Always commas between street, city, state, and US? Is state always spelled out or sometimes abbreviated (e.g. RI?)

Comment: There will be several ways to attack this, but whenever asking for help on a problem involving parsing character data it is vital that you include information on how _regular_ the data is, and what, if any, inconsistencies there may be. (Hence CephBirk's comment above.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The format is not always the same. For example sometimes it will be like "Apt XXX, state, city, US." But it always includes the full state name instead of the abbreviated one. Unfortunately, sometimes there will be typo in state name spelling, that's why I use NA in the last ifelse, so that I can see how many of them with typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem. This is one approach assuming that your address string always contains the full spelling of only one US state.

```
library(stringr)

# Get a list of all states
state.list = scan(text = "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina, North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia, Wisconsin, Wyoming", what = "",  sep = ",", strip.white = T)

# Extract state from vector address using library(stringr)
state = unlist(sapply(address, function(x) state.list[str_detect(x, state.list)]))

# Generate fake data to test
fake.address = paste0(replicate(10, paste(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS), 10, replace=TRUE), collapse="")), 
                      sample(state.list, 20, rep = T), 
                      replicate(10, paste(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS), 10, replace=TRUE), collapse="")))

# Test using fake address
unlist(sapply(fake.address, function(x) state.list[str_detect(x, state.list)]))
```

Output for fake address

```
      O4H8V0NYEHColoradoA5K5XK35LX           44NDPQVMZ8UtahMY0I4M3086        LJ0LJW8BOBFloridaP5H2QW8B81     521IHHC1MFCaliforniaG7QTYCJRO5 
                        "Colorado"                             "Utah"                          "Florida"                       "California" 
  YESTB7R6EPRhode IslandXEEGD4GEY3         5OHN2BR29HKansasCOKR9DY1WJ     4UXNJQW0QKNew MexicoH9GVQR3ZFY          5SYELTKO5HTexas3ONM1HU1VB 
                    "Rhode Island"                           "Kansas"                       "New Mexico"                            "Texas" 
    Z8MKKL7K1RWashingtonGEBS7LJUU0        WPRSQEI2CNIndiana141S0Z1M2E   O4H8V0NYEHNorth DakotaA5K5XK35LX  44NDPQVMZ8New HampshireMY0I4M3086 
                      "Washington"                          "Indiana"                     "North Dakota"                    "New Hampshire" 
LJ0LJW8BOBWest VirginiaP5H2QW8B811 LJ0LJW8BOBWest VirginiaP5H2QW8B812     521IHHC1MFNew JerseyG7QTYCJRO5      YESTB7R6EPWisconsinXEEGD4GEY3 
                        "Virginia"                    "West Virginia"                       "New Jersey"                        "Wisconsin" 
        5OHN2BR29HOregonCOKR9DY1WJ           4UXNJQW0QKOhioH9GVQR3ZFY   5SYELTKO5HRhode Island3ONM1HU1VB       Z8MKKL7K1ROklahomaGEBS7LJUU0 
                          "Oregon"                             "Ohio"                     "Rhode Island"                         "Oklahoma" 
          WPRSQEI2CNIowa141S0Z1M2E 
                            "Iowa"
```

edit: Use the following function based on `agrep()` for Fuzzy matching. Should work with minor spelling mistakes. You might need to go into edit comment to copy the code. The code contains an index-assign [<- operator called functionally, so the display is glitching here.

`unlist(sapply(fake.address, function(x) state.list[`[<-`((L<-as.logical(sapply(state.list, function(s) agrep(s, x)*1))),is.na(L),F)]))`

Comment: Check out the built-in `state.name` vector, part of base!

Comment: Never seem this constant. lol, it should be on this page: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Constants.html Is there a way to pull up all such constants?

Comment: It's not actually in `base`, it's in `datasets` (which is loaded by default). All documented in `?datasets`, click on `Index` for the listing.

Comment: It's cool. That's what I need when the state names are correctly spelled. But if there is a typo in state names, I could not see which one has a typo. How can I get the rows with typos?

Comment: The point is that you need to ?package to find the constants. I wonder if there is an equivalent to `data()` for constants.

Comment: Editted in solution that can fuzzy match. In addition, the matching can be tuned with optional parameters to `agrep()`

Comment: @Vlo `data()` works for `state.name` and `state.abb`. They are data, there's nothing special about them. `grep("state", data()$results)`. The only *actual* constants are those in `?Constants`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods.

First we need some sample data.

```
# some sample data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(addr=sprintf('123 street, Townville, %s, US',
                               sample(state.name, 25, replace=T)),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

If your data is super regular like that:

```
# the easy way, split on commas:
matrix(unlist(strsplit(dat$addr, ',')), ncol=4, byrow=T)
```

Method 2, use `grep` to search for values. This works even if no commas or different commas in different rows. (As long as the states always appear spelled the same way)

```
# get a list of state name matches; need to match ', state name,' otherwise
# West Virginia counts as Virginia...
matches <- sapply(paste0(', ', state.name, ','), grep, dat$addr)

# now pair up the state name with the row it matches to
state_df <- data.frame(state=rep(state.name, sapply(matches, length)),
                       row=unname(unlist(matches)),
                       stringsAsFactors=F)

# reorder based on position in original data.frame, and there you go!
dat$state <- state_df[order(state_df$row), 'state']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your formatting is consistent (sensu Joran's comment above), you could just parse with `strsplit` and then use `data.frame`:

```
address1<-"410 West Street, Small Town, MN, US"
address2<-"5844 Green Street, Foo Town, NY, US"
address3<-"875 Cardinal Lane, Placeville, CA, US"

vector<-c(address1,address2,address3)
df<-t(data.frame(strsplit(vector,", "))
colnames(df)<-c("Number","City","State","Country")
rownames(df)<-NULL

df
```

which produces:

```
     Number              City         State Country
[1,] "410 West Street"   "Small Town" "MN"  "US"   
[2,] "5844 Green Street" "Foo Town"   "NY"  "US"   
[3,] "875 Cardinal Lane" "Placeville" "CA"  "US"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be working in my tests:

```
 just.ST <- gsub( paste0(".+(", paste(state.name,collapse="|"), ").+$"),
        "\\1", address)
```

As mentioned in comments and illustrated in other answers, `state.name` should be available by default. It does have the deficiency that in case of a non-match it returns the whole string, but you can probably use:

```
  is.na(just.ST) <- nchar(just.ST) > max(nchar(state.name))
```